# Webpack dynamically replace url in scss while loading/Resolving

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, webpack-dev-server

I'm currently working on an Angular 4 project using Webpack.

I'd like to be able to customize my app main colors.

All my components SCSS files import a file named **color.scss** containing colors variables.

```
@import "src/assets/sass/color";
```

I have two files:

- src/assets/sass/_color.scss: default SCSS file.
- src/custom/A/assets/sass/_color.scss: customized SCSS file for **A**.

I'd like to tell webpack to replace this url when resolving, depending on a parameter I pass.

Therefore, when I execute:

```
webpack-dev-server --env.custom=A
```

Webpack would change all the imports of color.scss to "src/custom/A/assets/sass/color".

Is it possible ? If it is, how can it be implemented ?

Comment: Can you `@import "src/custom/A/assets/sass/color";` inside `src/assets/sass/_color.scss` then rebuild?

Comment: Yes but I cannot see how this would help. variables defined in the custom file are overriden by what it's defined in the main file.

Comment: Move the import to the bottom
(or is it the top?)

Comment: Does the custom css have variables or css rules?

Comment: the default and custom SCSS have the same structure (set of variables). Only their values change.
When moving the import at the bottom, It works. My app has the custom colors. But still, how can I tell webpack to add the import at the bottom of "src/assets/sass/color.scss" ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible with webpack. You could do it with a bash script if it's important

Comment: I was hoping I could avoid that ... using aliases or resolvers but I can't find a way

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of `src/assets/sass/_color.scss`

add `@import "src/custom/A/assets/sass/color";`

Then change `A` to when you want to swap colors.

Comment: Is it impossible to change the import url when webpack is resolving them ?
any rule for the sass-loader ?